# Delete rows based on multiple conditions; including other column conditionals

Tags: python, rows

I am seeking to drop some rows from a DataFrame based on two conditions needing to be met in the same row. So I have 5 columns, in which; if two columns have equal values (code1 and code2) AND one other column (count) is greater than 1, then when these two conditions are met in the same row - the column is dropped.

I could alternatively keep columns that meet the conditions of:

```
count == 1 'OR' (as opposed to AND) df_1.code1 != df_1.code2
```

In terms of the first idea what I am thinking is:

```
df_1 = '''drop row if''' [df_1.count == 1 & df_1.code1 == df_1.code2]
```

Here is what I have so far in terms of the second idea;

```
df_1 = df_1[df_1.count == 1 or df_1.code1 != df_1.code2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#building-criteria) to specify multiple conditions.

```
df_new = df_1.loc[(df_1.count != 1) & (df_1.code1 != df_1.code2), :]
```

Comment: Thank you! Works Smooth.

Answer (score 2):

```
df.drop(df[(df['code1'] == df['code2']) & (df['count'] > 1)].index, inplace=True)
```

Breaking it to steps:

`df[(df['code1'] == df['code2']) & (df['count'] > 1)]` returns a subset of rows from df where the value in `code1` equals to the value in `code2` and the value in `count` is greater than 1.

`.index` returns the indexes of those rows.

The last step is calling `df.drop()` that expects indexes to be dropped from the dataframe, and using `inplace=True` so we won't need to re-assign, ie
`df = df.drop(...)`.

Comment: Thank you for this. I didn't know you could combine conditionals into a one liner.